# How to create custom instances of bundle which contains a custom object?

Tags: java, android, object, android-recyclerview, bundle

I'm creating an Android app with two fragments. One contains getting input from an alert dialog box and creating an instance of a custom object.

This object is then sent to the another fragment using a Bundle and a function in the main activity.

After receiving the object as a bundle in the second fragment, I want to create a new instance of this custom object and adding it to recycler-view. The code now basically replaces the existing object.

I have tried creating new instances of the object before sending the bundle over.

FirstFragment.java

```
     Bundle data = new Bundle();
     SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy 'at' HH:mm");
                        String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());

      Mood moods = new Mood("smile",mood,currentDateandTime);
                        data.putSerializable("moods", moods);
                        ((MainActivity)getActivity()).saveData(data);
```

SecondFragment.java

```
    Bundle data = ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getSavedData();
    Mood moodx =  (Mood)data.getSerializable("moods");
 moods = new ArrayList<Mood>();
    moods.add(new Mood(moodx.getMood(), moodx.getReason(), moodx.getDate()));
```

MainActivity.java

```
    public void saveData (Bundle data) {
    this.dataBetweenFragment = data;
}

public Bundle getSavedData () {
    return this.dataBetweenFragment;
}
```

Comment: What's the question? can you please describe the problem you're facing

Comment: So basically in the fragment where it's supposed to display all the objects - instead of creating new objects in the list it just keeps replacing one single object. 

The entire project is on [Github](https://github.com/techydevil/Mr.Moody) please do compile it and check it out if you can.

Comment: As i went through your project I think you need first to find a way to keep your entries persisted (either some kind of database or save them on files). first when you do that you can start thinking about getting them all fetched and list them in one page

Comment: Oh thank you so much, can I use Firebase for this?

Comment: This might be an option too